# How to scroll a scrollable div when scrolled on other, non-scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, css

I know the question sounds confusing, but here is what I am trying to do - in the snippet below, if the user scrolls on the green div, I want the yellow div to be scrolled accordingly, just as if the yellow div was scrolled.

Note that the yellow div has `overflow: auto;` but the green one doesnt.

```js
document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('wheel', function(e){

  console.log('scrolled!');

  console.log(e.deltaX); // it is always "-0"

  // scroll div#yellow accordingly

});
```

```css
#yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding 20px;
}

#green{
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id='yellow'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
</div>

<div id='green'></div>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: maybe try overriding the scroll event on the window https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll

Comment: There is a CSS-only way by making `#yellow` fixed: `position: fixed`.

Comment: Made a plugin that fits the bill quite nicely. http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/

Comment: @martinweise That doesnt solve the problem though. I need to show the green div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the `deltaX` property, and what you need for vertical scrolling is the `deltaY` one.

```
document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('yellow').scrollTop += e.deltaY * 10;
});
```

Comment: Wow, have been looking for this the past 6 hours. Just after fiddling with the perfect title for my own question I stack suggested me this question! I'm just curious how this solution would work with jQuery; `$(".green").on("wheel", function(e) ...` doesn't seem to have `e.deltaY`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tbnmj817/)

```
document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {


  console.log(e.deltaY); // it is always "-0"

  // scroll div#yellow accordingly
  document.getElementById('yellow').scrollTop += e.deltaY;
});



#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding 20px;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}



<div id='yellow'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
</div>

<div id='green'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>


</div>
```